# create a new column that is a count of a filtered group

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have created a column in my Power BI to calculate the distinct count of TID by Attribute using the formula below and this works

```
ATTRIBUTE_TID_COUNT = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Customer Attributes'[Attribute]) ,
                      ALLEXCEPT('Customer Attributes', 'Customer Attributes'[TID]))
```

I need to add a filter where the `'Customer Attributes'[Attribute Type] = "Identifier"`

but I do not know how to add this filter to the column any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by adding a filter 'Customer Attributes'[Attribute Type] = "Identifier".
You want to add a slicer to the canvas or update a calculation of the column?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?? Because your current calculation only provide you 1 for each row. I think you are looking for a measure not a calculated column.

Comment: I needed the calculation to tell me how many specific types if unique attributes there are per TID, the repeated value would be for every row of the same TID, but each TID could have a different attribute total. This value had to be always look at the entire table and not re-calculate based on what data is filtered. For this reason the solution given by Alexis resolved my issue. Thanks for everyones help. I am gaining more knowledge from your answers and suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to simply add it as a filter argument to the `CALCULATE` function like this:

```
ATTRIBUTE_TID_COUNT =
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Customer Attributes'[Attribute] ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( 'Customer Attributes', 'Customer Attributes'[TID] ),
    'Customer Attributes'[Attribute Type] = "Identifier"
)
```

The [`CALCULATE` function](https://dax.guide/calculate/) takes tables or simple boolean filters.

Answer (score 0):

```
ATTRIBUTE_TID_COUNT = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Customer Attributes'[Attribute]) ,
                      FILTER('Customer Attributes', 'Customer Attributes'[Attribute Type] = "Identifier"))
```

Comment: Please add some comments to explain how your code answers the question in order to improve this answer.